# MS SQL backup fails

Tags: sql-server

Do anybody know, what this error is?

I can't backup a database from my MS SQL Server via Server Management Studio (Tools - Backup)

```
TITLE: Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio
------------------------------

Backup failed for Server 'SELEKSQL'.  (Microsoft.SqlServer.SmoExtended)

For help, click: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink?ProdName=Microsoft+SQL+Server&ProdVer=10.0.1600.22+((SQL_PreRelease).080709-1414+)&EvtSrc=Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.ExceptionTemplates.FailedOperationExceptionText&EvtID=Backup+Server&LinkId=20476

------------------------------
ADDITIONAL INFORMATION:

System.Data.SqlClient.SqlError: A nonrecoverable I/O error occurred on file "C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL10.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\Backup\Navision4.bak:" 112(failed to retrieve text for this error. Reason: 15105). (Microsoft.SqlServer.Smo)

For help, click: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink?ProdName=Microsoft+SQL+Server&ProdVer=10.0.1600.22+((SQL_PreRelease).080709-1414+)&LinkId=20476
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've come across error 15105 in low disk space situations. Verify that there is enough space on C: to complete the backup. Try backing up to another drive.